# How to scroll cutsom UITextFieldCell above UIKeyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit, uitextfield

I have a UITableView that uses a custom UITableViewCell. My UITableVewCell has two textfields inside it, which I have added a tag to in my main ViewController that holds the UITableView which houses my custom UITableViewCell.

So this is the code inside my `tableView:cellForRowAIndexPath:`

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomFCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

NSString *widthString = [currentFDictionary objectForKey:@"MM"];
        if ((NSNull *) widthString != [NSNull null]) {
            cell.widthTexField.text = widthString;
            cell.widthTexField.tag = indexPath.row;
        } else {
            cell.widthTexField.text = @" ";
        }

NSString *heightString = [currentFDictionary objectForKey:@"NM"];
        if ((NSNull *) heightString != [NSNull null]) {
            cell.heightTextField.text = heightString;
            cell.heightTextField.tag = indexPath.row;
        } else {
            cell.heightTextField.text = @" ";
        }


        return cell;
```

I would like to know how to then use this `.tag` to scroll the UITableViewCell above the UIKeyboard that will now be shown in the view.

Anyhelp would be greatly apprecited.

Comment: if you are using a custom cell xib then `cell = [[CustomFCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];` doesn't seem like it'll work... does it work for you? (_but this is not the main issue, just an observation_)

Answer (score 1):

A simple way i can think of is by using the `-scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:`

Set the delegate on the `UITextField` objects.

```
cell.widthTexField.delegate = self;
//...
cell.heightTextField.delegate = self;
```

Now, use `-textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` delegate method in this manner:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSIndexPath *currentSelectedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:currentSelectedIndexPath
                     atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop
                             animated:YES];
}
//NOTE: this way we don't really need to work with the textField tag per se
//(unless you are using it elsewhere as well)
//Instead, we work with the entire cell and scroll it to the desired position
```

---

*this may not be perfect since i haven't tested it here but it's the general idea*